# extract regexp result from string and write it to a variable

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script that searches in a file specified as argument $1 for a regex and writes the found subpattern into a variable I can then use.

let's say my script is called 'dosth.sh' and I have a file 'plot.gp' with the line

```
set output 'test.tex'
```

If I now execute 'dosth.sh plot.gp' the script should extract 'test.tex' from plot.gp and write it to a variable.

How is that possible with grep or others?

Thanks and regards, Jan Oliver

Comment: unix shell on mac os x. But I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

```
value=`cat $1 | grep -e 'set output' | cut -d'"' -f 2`
```

using " instead of ' and the line above does the job.

Comment: value=cat $1 | grep -e 'set output' | cut -d\" -f 2

Comment: -1 This has a number of issues, apart from the formatting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of

```
value=`grep '^set output' $x | cut -d' ' -f 3`
```

(Note that you will retain the quotes in `$value`

Comment: Thanks! Thats nearly what I want, besides those ' in the value.

Answer (score 0):

dosth.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE=`cat $1 | grep <your regexp here>`
echo $VALUE
```

this can be used as:

```
$ ./dosth.sh a.txt
```

then the found strings are stored in the variable `VALUE`

You can also give the regexp over by some arguments (asked for the filename by the script):

dosth.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Which file do you want to grep?"
read  FILENAME
args=("$@")
VALUE=`cat $FILENAME | grep $args`
echo $VALUE
```

which can be used like:

```
$ ./dosth.sh here comes my * pattern
```

Maybe this link is helpful for you: [Link](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is that I want a submatch of the pattern to be stored in my variable, not the hole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=$(sed -n '/^set output/ s/[^\x27]*\x27\([^\x27]*\)\x27/\1/p' "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

`value=$( awk -F"'" '$1 == "set output " {print $2}' somefile )`