# How to use grep to extract a substring?

Tags: regex, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extract regexp result from string and write it to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148558/extract-regexp-result-from-string-and-write-it-to-a-variable)

Here is my command :

> grep -E '\*[[:space:]]+FIN[[:space:]]+([^)]+?)') myfile

It outputs :

> - FIN (SUCCESS)

And I would like it outputs only :

> SUCCESS

How can I tell `grep` to do it ?

Comment: With plain traditional `grep`, you cannot. Use `grep -P` with a lookahead if you have that (slightly challenging) or switch to `sed` or `awk` or Perl or Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe the output of your grep command to the awk command.

```
grep -E '*[[:space:]]+FIN[[:space:]]+([^)]+?)') myfile | awk '{print $2}'
```

I am not sure how to do that with grep alone, as it is not really tailored to that exact use case. Since you are on a platform where grep is, use pipes to your advantage when you can have one command solve part of the problem, and another command the other part.

Comment: That's a Useless Use of Grep; `awk` has native and very idiomatic support for regular expressions.

Comment: very true. It's also easier to get the OP the answer he wants by simply adding the extra pipe. It can be debated which way to answer the question is better, and I fully agree telling the OP to only use awk is a valid answer as well.

Comment: So just for completeness `awk '/\*[[:space:]]+FIN[[:space:]]+([^)]+)/' { print $2 }' myfile`.  `awk` doesn't support `+?` but neither does `grep -E` actually, does it?  Also the leading asterisk should properly be quoted in all answers.

Comment: @tripleee the leading * was escaped but removed by the SO answer formatting system. I have updatd my question though.

Comment: If I am not mistaken { print $2 } gets the second word. The OP asked how to extract a substring, hence I think he's looking for a more generic solution. The ack method seems most appropriate

Answer (score 6):

`grep` is not capable of outputting a single capture group, but you can use `sed` to do it instead:

```
sed 's/\*[[:space:]]\+FIN[[:space:]]\+(\([^)]\+\))/\1/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that grep *can not* do that. Also, to be equivalent to a grep command, we should only print matched lines with a `sed -n 's/.../\1/p'`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com) then you can use match groups and the `--output` switch:

```
ack '\*\s+FIN\((.+?)\)' --output='$1' myfile
```