# Reading numbers from a text line in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to write a bash shell script, that opens a certain file `CATALOG.dat`, containing the following lines, made of both characters and numbers:

```
event_0133_pk.gz
event_0291_pk.gz
event_0298_pk.gz
event_0356_pk.gz
event_0501_pk.gz
```

What I wanna do is print the numbers (only the numbers) inside a new file `NUMBERS.dat`, using something like `> ./NUMBERS.dat`, to get:

```
0133
0291
0298
0356
0501
```

My problem is: how do I extract the numbers from the text lines? Is there something to make the script read just the number as a variable, like `event_0%d_pk.gz` in C/C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use grep to extract a substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569216/how-to-use-grep-to-extract-a-substring)

Comment: `tr -dc '[[:digit:]\n]' < CATALOG.dat > NUMBERS.dat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `grep` solution:

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+' CATALOG.dat >NUMBERS.dat
```

A `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' CATALOG.dat >NUMBERS.dat
```

And an `awk` solution:

```
awk -F"[^0-9]+" '{print $2}' CATALOG.dat >NUMBERS.dat
```

Comment: If you are using Perl-style regular expressions, you may as well use `\d` rather than `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for! :) And in case I needed to start a process, whenever the number comprised inside each line ranges between 200 and 300, how could I do that?

Comment: @urgeo I would suggest that you ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that you can achieve your result. One way would be to use awk:

```
awk -F_ '{print $2}' CATALOG.dat > NUMBERS.dat
```

This sets the field separator to an underscore, then prints the second field which contains the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**Awk**

```
awk 'gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")' infile
```

**Bash**

```
while read line; do echo ${line//[!0-9]}; done < infile
```

**tr**

```
tr -cd '[[:digit:]\n]' <infile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` command to extract the number part.

```
grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=_)' CATALOG.dat
```

gives output as

```
0133
0291
0298
0356
0501
```

Or

much simply

```
grep -oP '\d+' CATALOG.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need perl mode in grep for this. BREs can do this.

```
grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' CATALOG.dat > NUMBERS.dat
```